# Why IE in debug mode just skips errors and goes further, but without debugging it stops executing js?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, debugging, ie-developer-tools

I have some JS code that crashed in this place:

```
    alert("Before undefined error! "+i);        
 -> next = A[i][prop].nextSibling;
    alert("After undefined error! "+i);
```

The error occurs because `A[i]` is `undefined` and I got `'undefined' is null or not an object` error.

In the usual mode of execution, it just stops after second line, but when in debug mode (I use standard Developer Tools) execution of the code continues. Why?

Comment: Um, the debugger continues executing so you can find all of the JavaScript errors in fewer debugging sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the submenu of the Script panel in the IE Developer Tools, then click the configuration icon(or press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+O</kbd>). Check ["Break on Error"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625#_control)(or press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+E</kbd>) to stop execution at that point.